# How to make Tomcat stream media?

Tags: java, tomcat, streaming, media

I am entirely new to streaming implementation. I have developed some RESTful web services using Jersey/Tomcat. There are few cases where I need to send audio/video files to the clients, which uptil now I have been sending as a file fr download - now I want to stream these files.

Do I need to write some code for this ? Or I need some third party solutions ...I have heard about Wowza / Darwin / Red5...But I dont know if they can be integrated with Tomcat and my existing services. Any third party solutions need to be free / opensource, and they should support both audio and video streaming. In the near future I need to add transcoding support too..for which I am planning to use Xuggler. So it would be good if the server is having such support.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red5 is essentially Tomcat with added features. I don't know how far back in time the fork was made but the basic functionality is all there.

Also - Red5 and xuggler play nicely together.

You'd still need to code up the client side of the streaming portion though. Its possible that HTML 5 will give you this for cheap.

Comment: The wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems makes me think Red5 isnt a good option. Is it possible to integrate Flumotion with tomcat ?